# Direct3D11 4x MSAA enabled - still looking bad

Tags: antialiasing, directx11

I'm rendering a simple triangle using Direct3D11 and I'm seeing a very visible staircase pattern despite enabling 4x MSAA with quality level = 16 on the swap chain (I'm not even using any depth/stencil buffer at this time).

[image]

**Question: is this really what I should expect, or am I doing something wrong?** There's clearly some antialiasing going on, but I expected it to do a better job. Why is there a clear drop-off point forming the staircase - shouldn't it be smoother?

8x MSAA isn't looking much better:

[image]

Comment: MSAA has a fixed subpixel pattern. Maybe you have hit a bad angle (for this pattern). Do you have the same behavior at other angles?